# Drawing icons with font-face and :before content

Tags: html, css, less, font-face, pseudo-element

I have a little problem while creating icons with font-face and :before pseudo-class. I'm using LESS too. Right now, I have something like

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'myfontname';
    src: url('../myurl.eot');
    src: url('../myurl?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../myurl.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../myurl.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../myurl.svg#name') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.icon{
    font-family: 'myfontname';
    font-size: 1em;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.icon-correct:before{
        .icon; /*mixin*/
        position: relative;
        content:"\004C"; /*L in my font*/
        display: block;
}
```

And in my HTML

```
<span class="icon-correct"></span>
```

I can't see my icon doing it this way. However, it works if I do something like

```
<span class="icon">L</span>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: I cannot find any mistake in your code.. Is your LESS built correctly as expected?

Comment: maybe try to put the 'font family' on the pseudo element ..